# Find example: $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+\alpha h)-f(x_0-\beta h)}{(\alpha+\beta)h}\ \ \text{exists }\ \ \not\!\!\!\implies\ f'(x_0)\ \ \text{exists}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

> Assume that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function. For $x_0\in (a,b)$ and $\alpha,\beta>0$, we define the (asymetric) difference quotient
> $$(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(x_0):=\frac{f(x_0+\alpha h)-f(x_0-\beta h)}{(\alpha+\beta)h},\qquad h\neq 0.$$
> Given $\alpha,\beta>0$ with $\alpha\neq \beta$, I want to find an example of $f$ such that
> $$\lim_{h\to0}(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(x_0)\ \ \text{exists }\ \  \not\!\!\!\implies\ f'(x_0)\ \ \ \text{exists}.$$

This is a problem that I came up with while I'm preparing my recitation class as a teaching assistant in Analysis (I) course.

If $f'(x_0)$ exists, we can prove that $\lim_{h\to0}(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(x_0)=f'(x_0)$ by Taylor's theorem: It follows from $f(x_0+\alpha h)=f(x_0)+\alpha f'(x_0)h+o(h)$ and $f(x_0-\beta h)=f(x_0)-\beta f'(x_0)h+o(h)$ that $(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(x_0)=f'(x_0)+o(1)$ as $h\to0$, hence $\lim_{h\to0}(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(x_0)=f'(x_0)$.

Now, a natural question appears: What about the reverse problem? If $\alpha=\beta$, then for $f(x)=|x|$ and $x_0=0$ we have $(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(0)=0$ for all $h\neq0$, but $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.

However, for $\alpha\neq \beta$, I failed to find an example. I found that if $\alpha\neq \beta$, and if $f_-'(x_0)$, $f_+'(x_0)$ both exist, then we must have $$\lim_{h\to0}(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(x_0)\ \ \text{exists }\ \  \implies\ f'(x_0)\ \ \ \text{exists}.$$
So, for any example in which $\alpha\neq \beta$ and $\lim_{h\to0}(\Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}f)(x_0)\ \ \text{exists }\ \  \not\!\!\!\implies\ f'(x_0)\ \ \ \text{exists}$, there must be one of $f_-'(x_0)$ and $f_+'(x_0)$ that doesn't exist. (Note that $f$ should be continuous in this post.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about $f(x) = 2x$ when $x \ge 0$ and $f(x) = -x$ when $x < 0$. It is continuous and works for any $\beta = 2\alpha$?

Comment: @Gregory The right and left sided limits are not equal.

Comment: Was thinking about the counterexample $f(x) = |\beta x|$ for positive $x$ and $f(x) = | \alpha x| $ for negative $x$. This would have worked for $h \to 0^{+}$, but for negative $h$ we get a different limit. Starting from this idea of comparing negative and positive $x$, you can show that if the weird limit exists, then $lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{ f(x_0 - (\alpha/\beta) h) - f(x_0 - (\beta/\alpha) h) }{ h} $ exists. This is not analogous to the above limits, since both the arguments are at the left of $x_0$. One could search for a "multiplicative fractal" counterexample of factor $(\alpha/\beta)^2$

Comment: I mean something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837259/functions-invariant-under-scaling
But even simpler and constructed by hand, since we don't need such generality for parameters, nor smoothness. I was trying to define the function piecewise on intervals of the form $[\pm 2^{n}, \pm 2^{n+1}]$ for $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $\beta = 2, \alpha = 1$. However, this seems to mess up continuity in zero.

Comment: Relevant: [If $f$ is differentiable at $k$, find: $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(k + ph) - f(k - ph)}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131219/13130) Also, this [google search for "pseudo-symmetric derivative"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pseudo+symmetric+derivative%22&filter=0) and [*Parametric differentiation*](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/727320) by Evans/Humke (1981).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for your comment! It seems that the predecessors have considered more general “derivatives” than mine. This is interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to apologize... Thinking for more time leads to the conclusion that we cannot find any desired example. Let me explain.

> **Proposition.** Let $f$ be a function defined near $x_0\in\mathbb R$ and $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb R$  be such that $|\alpha|\neq |\beta|$. Assume that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, and
> $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+\alpha h)-f(x_0+\beta h)}{(\alpha-\beta)h}=A\in\mathbb R.$$
> Then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0)=A$.

*Proof.* Without loss of generality, we assume that $x_0=0$, $|\alpha|>|\beta|$ and $A=0$. Let $k=\frac\beta\alpha$, then $|k|<1$ and we have
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(kh)}{(1-k)h}=0.$$
We are going to prove that $f'(0)=0$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\left|\frac{f(h)-f(kh)}{(1-k)h}\right|<\epsilon,\qquad 0<|h|<\delta.$$
Now, for $0<|h|<\delta$, we have $0<|k^nh|<\delta$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_{>0}$, hence
$$\left|\frac{f\left(k^{n-1}h\right)-f\left(k^{n}h\right)}{h}\right|<(1-k)|k|^{n-1}\epsilon,\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb N_{>0},$$
and thus
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f\left(h\right)-f\left(k^{n}h\right)}{h}\right|&\leq\sum_{j=1}^n\left|\frac{f\left(k^{j-1}h\right)-f\left(k^{j}h\right)}{h}\right|\\
&<\sum_{j=1}^n(1-k)|k|^{j-1}\epsilon\\
&<\frac{1-k}{1-|k|}\epsilon, \qquad \forall n\in\mathbb N_{>0}.
\end{align*}
Letting $n\to\infty$, the continuity of $f$ at $x=0$ gives that
$$\left|\frac{f\left(h\right)-f\left(0\right)}{h}\right|\leq\frac{1-k}{1-|k|}\epsilon,\qquad 0<|h|<\delta.$$
Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. The proof is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too long for a comment, but I'm not sure how complete this is. Hopefully it is helpful.

Consider
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0^{\pm}} \frac{f(x_0+\alpha h)-f(x_0-\beta h)}{(\alpha+\beta)h} & = \lim_{h \to 0^{\pm}} \frac{f(x_0+\alpha h) - f(x_0) + f(x_0)-f(x_0-\beta h)}{(\alpha+\beta)h} \\ & = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} f'(x_0^{\pm}) + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} f'(x_0^{\mp}).
\end{align}
Now since $\lim_h\to0 \Delta_{\alpha,\beta,h}$ exists, we must have equality when taking the limit from either direction. This leads to
$$ (\alpha-\beta) f'(x_0^+) = (\alpha - \beta)f'(x_0^-).$$
By hypothesis if $\alpha \neq \beta$, we may cancel and have shown that $f'(x_0)$ exists.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I’ve noticed this. As I wrote in my post, for any desired example, there must be one of the right derivative and the left derivative that doesn’t exist. Thanks for writing the details of this fact!

Comment: What I am trying to say is that if $\alpha \neq \beta$, then no such example can exist. Because than the required equality can't be satisfied

Comment: Only if $\alpha = \beta$ can you then freely choose $f'(x_0^+)$ and $f'(x_0^-)$

Comment: You proved that if $f'(x_0^+)$ and $f'(x_0^-)$ both exist, then no such example can exist. We may probably find an example where $f'(x_0^+)$ and $f'(x_0^-)$ don’t exist.

Comment: I'm trying to say that I don't think there is.

Comment: Your continuity of the function implies that these left- right- handed derivatives exist. Can you describe an example where $f'(x_0^+)$ does not exist for a continuous function?

Comment: For example, $f(x)=x\sin\frac1x$.

Comment: These limits don't exist at 0 do they, from either direction... and hence the $\Delta$ function won't exist.

Comment: You split the limit of the sum into the sum of limits, neither of which is assumed to exist.